# Throwing Errors or Returning JSON When Registering User in ExpressJS Node

Tags: node.js, express

I am implementing a JSON API in Node ExpressJS and wondering if the best practice is to throw errors or return JSON to the caller indicating that something bad has happened.

This is my current implementation. If the username is already registered, I simply return back a message to the user. Should I be throwing an error instead etc?

```
const register = async (req, res) => {
    
    const { username, password } = req.body

    if (username.length == 0 || password.length == 0) {
        // SHOULD I THROW AN ERROR
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Username or password is missing.' })
        return
    }

    // check username is already registered 
    const existingUser = await models.User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: username
        }
    })

    if (existingUser) {
        // SHOULD I THROW AN ERROR
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Username already exists.' })
        return
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of [HTTP codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? So instead of sending back JSON. I should just send back HTTP status codes.

Comment: Yes, you are now sending status 200 which means that everything was ok, which is not true. You should rather send status 400 bad request with json that shows which fields are wrong